# loss function: mean pairwise squared error

Tags: tensorflow

When I use the

```
tf.losses.mean_pairwise_squared_error(labels, predictions, weights=1.0, scope=None, loss_collection=tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES)
```

function, I am sure the data is right. However, the loss on the tensorboard is always zero. I try hard to find it out, but do not know why? Following is the part of my code. Am I using the wrong shape?

```
score_a=tf.reshape(score,[-1])#shape: [1,39]
ys_a=tf.reshape(ys,[-1])#shape: [1,39]
with tf.name_scope('loss'):
loss=tf.losses.mean_pairwise_squared_error(score_a,ys_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `tf.losses.mean_pairwise_squared_error()`, `labels` and `predictions` should be of rank at least 2, because the first dimension will be used as `batch_size`. It means that you do not need to reshape `score_a` and `ys_a`. (I assume that `score_a` and `ys_a` have 39 entries and one batch.)

If `labels` and `predictions` are of rank 1, it means that all data entries are 0-tensor (scalar) so that the result of `tf.losses.mean_pairwise_squared_error()` becomes always zero.

One more thing. In my opinion, the current implementation (2018-01-03) of `tf.losses.mean_pairwise_squared_error()` looks imperfect. For example, as showin in the [API document of the function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_pairwise_squared_error), put the following data as `labels` and `predictions`:

`labels = tf.constant([[0., 0.5, 1.]])
predictions = tf.constant([[1., 1., 1.]])
tf.losses.mean_pairwise_squared_error(labels, predictions)`

In this case, the result should be `[(0-0.5)^2+(0-1)^2+(0.5-1)^2]/3=0.5` which is different from the result `0.3333333134651184` by tensorflow.

**[Update]** The bug (mentioned above) in `tf.losses.mean_pairwise_squared_error()` was fixed and applied from tensorflow 1.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing classification, you may have your `label` tensor with categorical value in one dimension. If that is the case, you will need to perform one hot transformation to match the shape of the predictions before calling `tf.losses.mean_pairwise_squared_error()`. You do not need to reshape the predictions.

```
labels_a = tf.one_hot(labels, 2)
```